# Arch linux greeter without DM

Tags: login, i3, display-manager, xinit

I'm using Arch Linux with `i3wm` with `xinit` which results in having tty1 as my "greeter".

I wanna know if there is any possibility to have a greeter, for instance, Deepin greeter at login prompt **without** having any display manager running. I am not sure if there is a way to call `xinit` before login and if that would solve the problem, but is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: From the [arch wiki Deepin](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Deepin_Desktop_Environment), it seems it's either started with xinit or it's using another DM like LightDM or GDM. What you call Deepin greeter is probably a theme around LightDM or GDM.

Comment: @Pierre-AlainTORET I see, the greeter is an inheritance from the DMs and Deepin just wrap a theme around it, right? So there is no apparent way to make this happen, right? Seems like I'd have to turn on a DM for the greeter and then off once I log in, which sounds completely awful

Comment: I wouldn't say it's an inheritance, it's the DM [itself](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Display_manager). Its role is to display a greeter and start the appropriate window manager when you login. Why would you stop it after you logged in ?

Comment: I'd like to use only `xinit` as it feels to drain fewer resources than a DM do. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Display_manager#Run_%7E/.xinitrc_as_a_session), you could try installing `xinit-xsession` to start the `.xinitrc` script from the login manager, which should be the same as running `startx`.

But if that's not the case and if it simply runs the `.xinitrc` as a script, you can try using [`greetd`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Greetd), which does not make any assumptions on what scripts to execute. [ReGreet](https://github.com/rharish101/ReGreet) is an example of a GTK4 based `greetd` greeter.

[image]